# Do you need to call transaction.RollBack if transaction.Commit fails for SQLX with posgres connection

Tags: go, sqlx

I am using

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx@v1.2.0

to connect to postgres and do queries.
Should I do transaction.Rollback if my transaction.Commit fails

Example

```
    tx, err := appState.PgConn.Beginx()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // then some queries using this tx reference
```

After that when we commit the transaction should we do ..
Approach 1

```
err:= tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    return err;
}
```

or should we use
Approach 2

```
err1 := tx.Commit()
if err1 != nil {
   err2:= tx.Rollback()
   if err2 !=nil {
      return err2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sqlx Tx type](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx@v1.2.0#Tx) is a wrapper around [`sql.Tx`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Tx) and the docs for that type state:

> After a call to Commit or Rollback, all operations on the transaction fail with ErrTxDone.

So calling `RollBack` after `Commit` (whether successful or not) will have no impact (and will return `ErrTxDone`). You can see this in the code [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=2262). This means that there is no reason to call `Rollback` after already calling `Commit` (so use Approach 1).